# Outputting read in NSMutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Problem:** I have read in values from Windows Azure. Through NSLogs I am able to see that my application does indeed read in from the table on the Azure Server. However Displaying the values has become a problem.

**Situation:** So far I have an NSMutableArray object in the ViewController.m file. I have accessed the array and been able to assign the values from the results of the read from the table (in windows azure) to the mutableArray. My problem is that I am trying to display it through a tableview however nothing displays, and when I move down the table view, the application crashes.

I believe the main problem is this line:

cell.textLabel.text = [clubs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Here is the ViewController.m code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{
    NSDictionary *courseDetails;
    NSArray *justCourseNames;

    NSDictionary *webcourseDetails;
    NSArray *webjustCourseNames;

    NSDictionary *clubNames;
    NSArray *location;

    NSMutableArray *clubs;
    NSInteger amount;



}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (section == 0)
    {
        return @"Milton Keynes";
    }
    else{
        return @"Stafford";
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return clubs.count;
    }
    else{
        return webcourseDetails.count;
    }

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ClubCellImage"];
    [cell.imageView setImage:image];

//removing the line of code below seems to fix the crash. this is the line of code to display the details

cell.textLabel.text = [clubs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    /*if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        //cell.textLabel.text = justCourseNames[indexPath.row];
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = courseDetails[justCourseNames[indexPath.row]];
    }
    else
     {
        cell.textLabel.text = clubs[indexPath.row];
        //cell.textLabel.text = webjustCourseNames[indexPath.row];
        //cell.detailTextLabel.text = webcourseDetails[webjustCourseNames[indexPath.row]];
    }*/


    return cell;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://clublocatortimogunmakin.azure-mobile.net/"
                                            applicationKey:@"ecxnaXEfNpeOvwYYgcViJJoumZlZng45"];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses" withExtension:@"plist"];
    MSTable *itemTable = [_client tableWithName:@"Item"];

    courseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url];
    justCourseNames = courseDetails.allKeys;

    NSURL *weburl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"courses_web" withExtension:@"plist"];

    webcourseDetails = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:weburl];
    webjustCourseNames = courseDetails.allKeys;

    [itemTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
        clubs = [results mutableCopy];
         amount = totalCount;
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            //NSLog(@"Item read, id: %@", [results objectAtIndex:1]);
            for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++)
            {
                NSLog(@"Item read, id: %@", [results objectAtIndex:i]);
            }
        }
    }];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log?

Comment: is this what you're looking for?16  CoreFoundation                      0x01cb236e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30

Answer (score 1):

You are contradicting yourself when you implement the required tableview datasource methods (i.e. the numberOfRowsInSection and the cellForRowAtIndexPath methods)

You provide the count of cells here:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return clubs.count;
    }
    else{
        return webcourseDetails.count;
    }

}
```

So, your cellForRowAtIndexPath method should look something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    // cell init/dequeuing 



    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = clubs[indexPath.row]; //Assuming that is an NSString instance
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = webcourseDetails[indexPath.row]; //Assuming that is an NSString instance
    }


    return cell;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, That has resolved the crash now! however no data is being output onto the table yet? I know 100% its being read because I have the details being printed out in the log :S help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Please, try to do the following (I think you're not re-loading table after all items are read):

```
[itemTable readWithCompletion:^(NSArray *results, NSInteger totalCount, NSError *error) {
    clubs = [results mutableCopy];
     amount = totalCount;
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"Item read, id: %@", [results objectAtIndex:1]);
        for (int i = 0; i < results.count; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Item read, id: %@", [results objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
        [YOURTABLENAMEHERE reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Replace **YOURTABLENAMEHERE** with a reference to your table.